# how to retrieve pdf file from database (varbinary max) from excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've no idea about how to retrieve or extract pdf file from database through excel vba? *(there is lot of help available in c#,asp...)*

File stored in varbinary max type field in SQL Server Databse.

I can connect or access the recordset through VBA after that how to extract it from the that recordset

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

'Here I use default admin user 'sa' and password is blank
cn.Open "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
        "Data Source=ServerNameOrIP;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=DBName;" & _
        "User ID=sa;" & _
        "Password=;"""

'your sql statment including varbinary max field here it is FILEDATA
sql = " select EMAILID,EMAILFROM,EMAILTO,EMAILSUBJECT,FILEDATA from Tbl "


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open sql, cn

Do Until rs.EOF
    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream
    With oStream
         .Type = adTypeBinary
         .Open
         .Write rs.Fields(4).Value
         'Here I use 1st field value as file name i.e. rs.fiedls(0).value 
         'In addition you can join drive and/or folder path to save another location
         .SaveToFile rs.Fields(0).Value & ".pdf", adSaveCreateOverWrite
         .Close
    End With
    Set oStream = Nothing
    rs.MoveNext
Loop


rs.Close
cn.Close
```